# Efficiently Match Usernames With @ Symbol In A String Using C#

Tags: c#, regex, string-matching

I want to be able to efficiently pick out usernames in a string, and then hyperlink them to a users profile. Just like Facebook does.

But the problem comes when people do things like this for @Username

"Some words @Username... some words"
"Some words @Username! some words"

Any idea how I might still pick out just the username, and then hyperlink it without getting the extra characters after the end of their Username?

Comment: Well, you've tagged this with `regex` already, which sounds like a good idea... now, have you tried *any* regular expressions yet?

Comment: What characters are allowed in a username (ex: `.,!`)? What's the plan for someone who can'tpress thespa cebar corr e ctly? Does capitalization matter? (ie is `@UseRName` equivalent to `@username`)

Comment: [`/@([A-Z]+)/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/dW9yJ2/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like trying to solve these using the framework:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "Some words @Username1... some words",
    "Some words @Username2! some words"
};

var items = list.Select(str => string.Concat(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('@') + 1).TakeWhile(char.IsLetterOrDigit)));
//items = ["Username1", "Username2"]
```

you'll need to do some exception handling for bad strings of course.  And you can change `char.IsLetterOrDigit` to `IsLetter` if digits are not allowed.